# How to excute the binary excutable file in my Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using node.js in my server side. Now I wanna run some binary file compiled from a .c code, how to do that?

I've already tried 
`var obj = new ActiveXObject("WwScript.Shell");
obj.run("myBinary");`

But doesn't work... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you're looking for [child_process.exec](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/child_processes.html#child_process.exec).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec("/path/to/your/Binary", function(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) });
```

***Update:***
It seems that `sys` module is is deprecated, use `util` instead as @loganfsmyth mentioned.

```
var exec  = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('/path/to/your/Binary',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
    console.log('stderr:', stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error:', error);
    }
});
```

Comment: The `sys` module is is deprecated. `util` took it's place. Why bother though, just use `console.log()` or `process.stdout.write()`

Answer (score 0):

The below code snippet from [codegrepper.com](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/nodejs+execute+binary+file+and+get+output) worked for me :)

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");    
    exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
```